# Android WebView chamar discador pelo link

Tags: javascript, android, webview

Olá, estou desenvolvendo um WebApp de um guia de telefones, no site tenho a opção de clicar em um botão para abrir o discador do celular já com o número de telefone. Mas no WebApp não funciona, me mostra a "Página não encontrada".

Este é o link que estou utilizando:

```html
<a href="tel:3326 3728">Ligar</a>
```

Comment: bom dia , onde vou colocar esse codigo?

Answer (score -1):

Segue o trecho do código que solucionou essa questão:

```
myWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView myWebview, String url) {
        if (url.startsWith("tel:")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(intent);
            myWebview.reload();
            return false;
        }

        myWebview.loadUrl(url);
        return false;
    }

});
```